# List contains Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code trying to query some data from Firestore using GeoFlutterFire, but for the sake of efficiency I want to fetch the list of ids only once, then use it to fetch the rest of the data from Firebase Database.
This is the code in question:

```
class _StartScreenState extends State<StartScreen> {

  List ids = ['abc'];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('ids ${ids}');
  }

  _initState() async {
    Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
    List ids1 = [];

    Geoflutterfire geo = Geoflutterfire();
    var location = new Location();
    var pos = await location.getLocation();
    GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude.toDouble(), longitude: pos.longitude.toDouble());

    var collectionReference = _firestore.collection('locations');
    var geoRef = geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference);
    return ids1.add(geoRef.within(center: center, radius: 50, field: 'position', strictMode: true).first.then((value) {
      value.map((doc) {

        if (doc.data.isNotEmpty) {
          print('doooc id here ${doc['id']}');
          ids1.add(doc['id']);
          print(ids1);

        }
      }).toList();
      setState(() {
        ids = ids1;
        print('setting state to ids ids print: ${ids.}');
      });
    }));

  }
```

Like I said, my intent is to fetch the Ids and once I have the list check if there's some related data in Firebase, but I'm not sure this is the way I should do it and there's something that I don't know how to awoid; When I print the list I get the following result:

> setting state to ids ids print: [Instance of 'Future',
>   3esdWesqrTD_123_3dssds3, sQWdsda23dsad_da21]

Can anyone tell me why I have this Instance of 'Future' in my List and how can avoid it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried to run your code, but I suspect the issue starts with the statement

```
return ids1.add(geoRef.within(center: center, radius: 50, field: 'position', strictMode: true).first.then((value) {
```

As you can see, you are adding something `ids1.add(...)` that looks like it needs to `await`: `geoRef.within(...).first.(...)`. I don't find the `ids1.add(...)` call needed in the return statement. Try removing it, and see how it goes.